# Unable to fetch terraform list variables dynamically

Tags: terraform

I have a list variable "test" in variables.tf. I am trying to use this list variable inside my zone.tf .

I do not want to use list indexes here infact I want to run a loop to get all the values of the list from list variable dynamically. How can I accomplish this ? Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried to use count in test.tf inside resource resource "aws_route53_record" but it creates multiple record sets which I do not want as I just need a single record set with multiple records

```
   resource "aws_route53_record" "test" {
      zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.dns.zone_id}"
      name    = "${lower(var.environment)}xyz"
      type    = "CAA"
      ttl     = 300
      count = "${length(var.test)}"
     records = [
        "0 issue \"${element(var.test, count.index)}\"",
      ]
    }
```

variables.tf  :-

```
variable "test" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["godaddy.com", "Namecheap.org"]
}




zone.tf :-

resource "aws_route53_record" "test" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.dns.zone_id}"
  name    = "${lower(var.environment)}xyz"
  type    = "CAA"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [
    "0 issue \"${var.test[0]}\"",
    "0 issue \"${var.test[1]}\"",
  ]
}
```

Expecting to get the one record set with two records.

Actual :- getting Two record sets with two records.

Answer (score 0):

so if I am understanding correctly you want to associate two records with your zone, but right now when using count you are getting two zones with one record.

This is because by specifying county terraform will create the resource that has the count attribute on it equal to the number of count.

The issue is fundamentally that right now you have a list variable and are trying to pass it to where a list is expected by extracting each individual element of the list to put back element by element into the list attribute.

Rather than go through that additional work an easier solution would be to just add the additional parts of the string, the "0 issue" part to the definition of the variable and then just pass the whole list object in as shown below

```
variable "test" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["0 issue godaddy.com", "0 issue Namecheap.org"]
}

zone.tf :-

resource "aws_route53_record" "test" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.dns.zone_id}"
  name    = "${lower(var.environment)}xyz"
  type    = "CAA"
  ttl     = 300
  records = ["${var.test}"]
}
```

This will then pass the list in for that attribute and terraform will take care of the marshaling and unmarshaling and handling of the list. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: If the need is to go from just the hostnames to the longer strings, this could be achieved by additionally using `formatlist("0 issue %s", var.test)` to format each list item in turn, as an alternative to doing that manually in the variable default.